# Better way to delete unused tag. / django taggit python

Tags: python, django, django-taggit

Hi i'm python django beginner.

I'm creating a simple blog

and i want to delete tags that are not used while deleting a post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modify_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    tags = TaggableManager(blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='owner', blank=True, null=True)
```

```
class PostDelete(WriterCheckMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):    
        temp = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])
        for tag in temp.tags.all():
            if tag.taggit_taggeditem_items.count() <= 1:
                tag.delete()
        return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I just follow tutorial so don't know what happens behind DeleteView.

It worked as intended but seems inefficient.

Do i need "temp = Post.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk'])"?

Please give me advices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can delete unused tags with:

```
from django.db.models import Count
from taggit.models import Tag

class PostDelete(WriterCheckMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:list')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().delete(request, *args, **kwargs)
        finally:
            Tag.objects.annotate(
                ntag=Count('taggit_taggeditem_items')
            ).filter(ntag=0).delete()
```

This will thus annotate the queryset, and remove the tags with no related items.

That being said, I am not sure why you per se need to remove unused tags. You can decide to only *render* tags that have one item. But storing tags in the database, will normally not result in large amounts of disk usage anyway.